# Reportlab - how to introduce line break if the paragraph is too long for a line

Tags: python, pdf-generation, newline, reportlab

I have a list of text to be added to a reportlab frame

```
style = getSampleStyleSheet()['Normal']
style.wordWrap = 'LTR'
style.leading = 12
for legend in legends:
    elements.append(Paragraph(str(legend),style))
```

If the legend is too long, the text at the end is not visible at all.
How to introduce line breaks in this situation.

Comment: I recommend yo to post this to reportlab-users@lists2.reportlab.com, mailing lists probably are not very cool, but ReportLab mailing list is still the best source for info :)

Comment: @juanefren Does this still true? I found the documentation is still very shallow.

Answer (score 29):

This may or may not apply but I just learned that `\n` which I normally use to introduce new lines in Python strings gets ignored by the Paragraph object of ReportLab.

From a [mailing list](http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2007-July/006135.html) I learned that inside Paragraph you can use HTML's `<br/>` to introduce the new line instead.

That works well for me.

Comment: `<br/>` and `<br />` work. But `<br>` raises a `ValueError: paraparser: syntax error: No content allowed in br tag`

Comment: ReportLab uses an XML parser so it's more XHTML than HTML meaning you must have a closing tag.

Comment: Some time  White-space before and after string, cause an error during report generations.

Answer (score 14):

As [PolyGeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/820534/polygeo) says, you can use `<br />` to add new lines to a Paragraph.

**Convert new lines to `<br />` tags**

```
replace('\n','<br />\n')
```

**Updated code**

```
 for legend in legends:
        content = str(legend).replace('\n','<br />\n')
        elements.append(Paragraph(content, style))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style.wordWrap = 'LTR'
```

Sorry if I misunderstood this as *letter*, but Paragraph itself is "word wrapped", in relation to document pagesize also.

There's userguide value of 'CJK' for Asian language, possibly your setting do the text to search for finishing line according to something else, like Asian language word splitting. Set it to None should do the thing.