# How to insert a carriage return in a ReportLab paragraph?

Tags: python, reportlab

Is there a way to insert a carriage return in a Paragraph in ReportLab? I am trying to concatenate a "\n" to my paragraph string but this isnt working.

```
Title = Paragraph("Title" + "\n" + "Page", myStyle)
```

I want to do this since I am putting names into cells and want to control how many names lie on a line in a cell (ideally 1). One cell can contain multiple names but within that cell i would like each name to be on its own line, hence the need to insert a new line.

At some point im getting a flowable to large for frame error  (I think it has something to do with a table being too large OR having too many merged rows). The only way i can think to suppress this is to have only one name per line in a cell so that i can limit table size based on a count of names and segment the tables into smaller tables.

Seems like there has to be a much cleaner way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Paragraph` is a `Flowable` in reportlab. A newline character will not work within a flowable in the way you want it to. If your `Paragraph` is within a table (as you suggest), you might consider creating a cell without a flowable. For example, you might do this:

```
data = [['Title\nPage', 'Name', 'Exists'],  # note the newline character
        ['', 'George', 'True']]
t = Table(data, style=style_)
...
```

The above example will make the first data cell two rows tall (but part of the same cell).

If you really need to preserve the style of the `Paragraph` flowable, however, you could insert two paragraphs into the same cell:

```
title1 = Paragraph("Title", myStyle)
title2 = Paragraph("Page", myStyle)
cell = [title1, title2]               # put this in a single cell of your table
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to start a new paragraph (regardless of whether you are in a table or not), you can use the `<br/>` tag. This should work for you as well:

```
Title = Paragraph("Title" + "<br/>" + "Page", myStyle)
```

(credit: [Reportlab - how to introduce line break if the paragraph is too long for a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816006/reportlab-how-to-introduce-line-break-if-the-paragraph-is-too-long-for-a-line))

Comment: `<br>` will raise `ValueError: paraparser: syntax error: No content allowed in br tag`  But `<br/>` or `<br />` [both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/462741/673991) work fine.