# Text Wrapping in a Text Object ReportLab

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to enable text wrapping in ReportLab, meaning if the string goes over a certain width, it wraps down.

I tried using the following approach:

`textobject.textLine(text="I put a very, very long string here")`

However, the string didn't wrap, but instead went off the screen. Because that approach didn't work, I tried the method with Paragraphs:

`textobject.textLine(text=Paragraph("I put a very, very long string here"))`

However, I got the following error with this approach: `TypeError: 'Paragraph' object is not iterable`. Given that these approaches don't work, how can I implement a multiline wrap for text?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Paragraph` since it has a `wrap` method which allows us to calculate the `width` and `height` of the `text` given a `max_width` and `max_height`.

Although the `Paragraph` object is not iterable, when we `drawOn` with our newly calculated `width` and `height` parameters, `paragraph`'s `'lines'` (accessed via `'blPara'`) will be grouped within our set parameters:

```
text = '''
Some text here. More text. So much text. It continues on and on. Even more text.
Another line of text.
'''
canv = Canvas('doc.pdf')
paragraph = Paragraph(text, style)
start_width = 0
max_width = 500
max_height = 100
width, height = paragraph.wrap(max_width, max_height)
paragraph.drawOn(canv, start_width, height, _sW=width)
print(paragraph.__dict__['blPara'].__dict__['lines'])
```

Outputs:

```
[(52.540000000000305, ['Some', 'text', 'here.', 'More', 'text.', 'So', 'much', 'text.', 'It', 'continues', 'on', 'and', 'on.', 'Even', 'more', 'text.', 'Another', 'line', 'of', 'text.'])]
```

Which is the `text` comprising of a single line that has `52.540000000000305` space left.

But if we set our `max_width` to `100` then we get multiple lines of `text` that are less than `100`:

```
[(3.8499999999999943, ['Some', 'text', 'here.', 'More']), (8.83999999999999, ['text.', 'So', 'much', 'text.', 'It']), (7.159999999999997, ['continues', 'on', 'and', 'on.']), (29.97, ['Even', 'more', 'text.']), (13.83999999999999, ['Another', 'line', 'of', 'text.'])]
```

Or maybe you're looking for this ([Reportlab - how to introduce line break if the paragraph is too long for a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816006/reportlab-how-to-introduce-line-break-if-the-paragraph-is-too-long-for-a-line)) as an answer.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer this would work but I would like to stick with text objects and not have to use paragraphs

Comment: @Choccy_vr sorry I thought your question meant otherwise, let me update my answer just give me a moment.

Comment: No worries actually I just switched to paragraphs for the text that needs to be wrapped thank you for giving me the idea

Comment: @Choccy_vr glad I could help! I'd appreciate it if you accepted/upvoted my answer, thanks!

Comment: sorry sadly I don't have enough reputation

Comment: @Choccy_vr you can accept without reputation if I answered your question.